# Is there a Oracle data dictionary table that associates trigger and its audit table?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Is there a Oracle data dictionary table that associates a trigger with its trigger audit table?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMo64.png)

Comment: Please post text as text, not an image of text.

Comment: all_dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You can check out `DBA_DEPENDENCIES`

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM dba_dependencies
 WHERE TYPE = 'TRIGGER' AND referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: Thank you EJ Egyed. I sure appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Query `user_dependencies`.

For example:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    before insert on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into dept (deptno) values (:new.deptno);
  6    insert into owner (id_owner, name) values (:new.empno, :new.ename);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select referenced_name, referenced_type
  2  from user_dependencies
  3  where referenced_owner = user
  4    and name = 'TRG_TEST';

REFERENCED_NAME      REFERENCED_TYPE
-------------------- ------------------
DEPT                 TABLE     --> trigger line #5
EMP                  TABLE     --> trigger line #2
OWNER                TABLE     --> trigger line #6

SQL>
```

---

Bonus: there's that nice view called **dictionary**. If you query it, it reveals useful information and shows which tables (views) you could try to query to find information you need. In this very case:

```
SQL> select table_name, comments
  2  from dictionary
  3  where lower(comments) like '%dependenc%';

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
ALL_DEPENDENCIES               Dependencies to and from objects accessible to the user
ALL_XSC_SECURITY_CLASS_DEP     All security class dependencies in the database
USER_DEPENDENCIES              Dependencies to and from a users objects

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot. I sure appreciate it.